# Size of a pointer referring nothing

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sizeof

I have a problem with sizeof(). I have a pointer in a class that I have created before. And this pointer is initialized as

```
 static Book* books;
```

so it does point nothing. I want to determine if the pointer does point any array or not. So first question is that what are the solutions to do that because I can change the address of this pointer during the runtime to point an array. I try to use sizeof(pointer) but it does not help me enough. The return is the number 4. I can evaluate in this way if it refers anything or not.

This is my class :

```
class Tool
{

private:
    static Book* books;

public:

    static char* pgetStringIntoArray(string);
    static string* pgetStringFromArray(char*);
    static void printCharArray(char*);
    static bool* addBook(Book*);
    static bool* isStored(Book*);
};
```

And this is the method having a problem :

```
bool* Tool::isStored(Book* book)
{
    bool* stored = new bool(false);
    if(Tool::books)
    {
        cout << "NULL"  << endl;
    } else {
        return stored;
    }

}
```

Comment: `sizeof(books)` is just a convenient alternative for `sizeof(Book*)`. In standard C++, `sizeof` is always evaluated at compile time and will never actually inspect the value at runtime. It just looks at the types involved. You can even write `sizeof(1/0)` without getting a division-by-zero error ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the sizeof(a pointer pointing to an array)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't use `sizeof` to determine if the pointer is pointing to something. `sizeof` a pointer will be always the same size in the same architecture.

You can do this:

```
Tool::Book* books = NULL;
```

And, if you want to check if it's pointing to a valid non-null value, just do:

```
if (Tool::books) {
    // books is pointing to something
}
```

Whenever you allocate memory for your pointer (array), if the allocation succeeds, the pointer will no longer be null. Since you are using `C++`, consider using `std::vector` to hold arrays of dynamic dimensions instead of arrays (pointers).

Comment: Thx but the compiler gives me an error :
error: invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type ‘Book*’

Comment: Ok but now it says in the if statement this : undefined reference to `Tool::books'

Comment: @ErayTuncer: *what* if statement?

Comment: I expended the post above you can find the if statement part and it says undefined reference to `Tool::books'

Comment: @ErayTuncer: now that we can see more code, I updated the answer.

Comment: Did you include the header file in the cpp?

Comment: @ErayTuncer: why are all your methods static, by the way?

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz Still does not work. Why did you say
static Tool::Book* books = NULL; 
the pointer books is already in the class Tool :S

Comment: @smocking Yes I have included the header. There are more methods working in the cpp already.

Comment: Since it's static, you will have to declare it in the cpp as well: `Book* Tool::books;`. BTW from the lack of `std::`, it seems like you're `using namespace std` in your header file. Better avoid that to save trouble in the future.

Comment: @smocking Yeah that solved my problem. Thank you all for your attention :)

Answer (score 1):

Much like C, C++ is statically typed - the various type sizes as returned by the `sizeof` operator are determined at compile time and do not change.

The proper way to do what you are asking would be to initialize your pointer to `NULL` and check for that afterwards. `NULL` is guaranteed not to refer to any valid memory address, which makes it a good marker for a non-existent pointer target. Initializing your pointers is a good practice anyway - it saves you from potential issues from dereferencing uninitialized pointers, issues that at best will result in nasty memory errors.

And yes, explicitly initializing the rest of your variables is also a good idea...

**EDIT:**

One not-so-minor detail: static fields in C and C++ programs are stored in a special section (e.g. [BSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss)) of the executable and are automatically initialized to zero as the program loads. Therefore, you do not need to explicitly initialize static pointers to `NULL`; that has already been done for you...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is more with understanding pointers than with `sizeof`.

`sizeof` is a *compile-time* operation. For a pointer it always return `sizeof(void*)`  (which is 8 bytes on most 64 bits architectures). Except for [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s, `sizeof` returns a compile time constant.

C don't know the used size of any pointed zone -think of the result of `malloc` as an example- (because you could do pointer arithmetic). You need to manage it by yourself if needed.